# How do loggers flush without adding an end of line to the log messages?

Tags: c++, logging, flush, eol, endl

I have seen many loggers using `operator<<` to read log messages and write them on file:

```
template<typename T>
Logger& Logger::operator<<(Logger& l, const T& s) {
    l.logStream << s;
    return l;
}

...

Logger log;
log << "Test message " << 123;
```

I want the log to be flushed after `"Test message"` and `123` are written to the stream. However, rather than the user being in control of the flushing, I want the logger to flush the stream when it reaches the `;`.

How can I do that?

Two solutions came to my mind, but I find both not acceptable:

I could put the new line at the beginning of each log message, so that the previous log is flushed, and in case of a crash all we loose is the current log.

`operator<<` could flush. But flushing on each invocation of `<<` incurs a big performance penalty due to the number of write operations on disk (wearing). I want the flush to involve the whole message.

Comment: [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)?

Comment: Some logger libraries have `operator<<` returning a temporary with `std::flush` in its destructor.

Comment: @G.M. - `std::flush` does not change much, and I added it to the list of examples.

Comment: I don't get your question. A logger can be implemented to do anything. It can flush on every `<<` call for example. Also: what does line terminator have to do with flushing?

Comment: @Jarod42 - Interesting. If you expand it in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @freakish - Sure, but it is not efficient nor healthy for the disk.

Comment: Formatted output operators (`operator <<`) construct an object of type [`std::basic_ostream::sentry`}(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/sentry) on entry. The sentry object's destructor flushes the stream if the `unitbuf` flag is set. That's how `std::cerr`, for example, works.

Comment: @Pietro maybe it is, maybe it isn't. That's a completely different question.

Comment: @Pietro -- flushing a file stream doesn't necessarily write to the disk. All it does is flush the stream's buffer into whatever the hardware provides, typically another buffer.

Comment: @PeteBecker, @ freakish - I just updated my question, which now keeps your comments in consideration.

Comment: Please provide the implementation of `Logger::logStream`.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Well, typically if I unplug my PC before a flush I loose the data, if I do it after my data is safe. So I think the default behavior is to write on disk after each flush.

Comment: @Pietro if you really want logging to be efficient, then you should consider pushing logs to a (thread safe) queue and let a background worker (thread) write them to disk. You can then tune it to flush after X writes.

Comment: Also the only way to ensure that everything was written is to flush after each write. You  are either efficient or consistent. You cannot satisfy both requirements at the same time. That being said I strongly recommend to not worry about lost logs, unless you are writing a database engine or something.

Comment: @freakish - I want to flush whole log messages, one by one. Not tokens of log messages (for the reason I explained). And this applies to the case of a background worker thread, too.

Comment: @freakish: Now the question is what is a "write" :) in `log << "TestMessage" << 123`, do we "write" the whole line, each characters, the first string, then the number...

Comment: its not clear where you miss the `endl`. here `log << "Test message " << 123;` or in the implementation?

Comment: @Pietro then flush on each `<<`, I already said that.

Comment: @Jarod42 "write" as in "write syscall".

Comment: @Jarod42 - I would like `"TestMessage" << 123` to be flushed all together, in a single operation.

Comment: @Pietro It seems like you want the log to be flushed at the end of the expression (when you reach `;`). This is possible by using a proxy object (have the first `operator<<` return a temporary object, and then flush on its destruction). However, this isn't ideal. You are hard coding when a flush occurs, forcing the behaviour on the user, even if they want to add more output before flushing. This is basically the same problem you are trying to avoid by not flushing at every `operator<<`. Let the user flush when they want by passing `std::flush` instead.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - I would like to avoid using `endl` (or equivalent) in the logs, but still have the buffer with the whole log message flushed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I do not want the user to care about flushing. All I want is to flush each whole log message as soon as it is produced (i.e. when I reach `;`). If you could show in an answer the approach using the temporary object and its destructor, I would accept it.

Comment: really no offense, but the question is rather unclear. You say you do not want `std::flush` afer the message but it turned out you do want `std::flush` after the message. I will try to edit, when Im done please review and edit to your likings (or simply rollback)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - As I wrote in my question, I would consider the option not to flush at the end of the `log << "Test message " << 123;` line, but at the beginning of the following `log << "Test message 2";` line.

Comment: I was refering to your comment " I would like "TestMessage" << 123 to be flushed all together" this means you do want to flush after that message. In the question it was written that you do not want to flush after the message. I do now understand that you meant you do not want the user to write `log << "TestMessage" << 123 << std:;flush;` and the flush should happen automatically. If this understanding is still wrong you should fix my edit and clarify

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - That is exactly what I meant. Thank you for making my question clearer.

Comment: btw I suspect there is still a little misundersanding, because I do not see how flushing beofre the message would make any difference. Do you plan to create a new `Logger log` instance for a second log message? If thats the case the implementation suggested in my answer can be simpler, because no proxy is needed.  It can be simply `Logger{} << "Blabla" << 123;` and getting flushed in `Logger` destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like "TestMessage" << 123 to be flushed all together, in a single operation.

You can do that by returning a proxy object from `log::operator<<` that has its own `proxy::operator<<` which forwards to `log::operator<<`, and flushes in its destructor.

Something along the line of

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Logger {
    std::ostream& out = std::cout;
};

struct ProxyLogger {
      Logger& l;
      explicit ProxyLogger(Logger& l) : l(l) {}
      
      template <typename T>
      ProxyLogger& operator<<(const T& s) {
           l.out << s; 
           return *this;
      }
      ~ProxyLogger();
};

template<typename T>
ProxyLogger operator<<(Logger& l, const T& s) {
    l.out << s;
    return ProxyLogger(l);
}

ProxyLogger::~ProxyLogger() { l.out << "hello proxy" << std::flush; }

int main() {
    Logger log;
    log << "test" << 123;
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/1qjxsjsKb):

```
test123hello proxy
```

The proxy adds `hello proxy` to the message in its destructor for illustration.

The code you posted is somewhat bogus. Your `operator<<` is a member function but has an additional `Logger&` parameter. Thats not how you are going to get `log << "test";` to work. Make it either a friend with the explicit argument or a member without.

Moreoever, a templated `operator<<` looks rather cool at first, but as soon as you want to handle iomanipulators, as eg `std::flush`, things get hairy, because most of them are function templates. I avoided passing the iomanipulator through `Logger::operator<<` by letting the proxy pipe to the stream directly. You may want to make the `Logger`s stream private and the proxy a friend. Making io manipulators actually work with this approach I consider as beyond the scope of this question.

For further reading I refer you to articles about RAII (resource acquisition is initialization).

Comment: I see `Logger::operator<<` still returns a `Logger` object, not a `ProxyLogger`...

Comment: @Pietro look at the return type, then consider what constructors the proxy has

Comment: Do you mean line `return l;` is equivalent to `return ProxyLogger(l);`?

Comment: @Pietro I dont think it is equivalent, but yes, a `ProxyLogger` is returned that is constructed from `l`

Comment: @Jarod42 - I asked because `ProxyLogger` and `Logger` are not one derived from the other...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai - If you fix it now, I will accept it twice ;-)

Comment: @Pietro [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification of @463035818_is_not_an_ai answer, where I add a preprocessor flag to switch between the classic and proxy version of his code, with an `abort` call after the log, and show that only in the second case the log message is saved. De-comment line `#define PROXY` to switch:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

//#define PROXY

struct Logger {
    std::ostream& out = std::cout;

#ifndef PROXY
    template<typename T>
    Logger operator<<(const T& s) {
        out << s;
        return *this;
    }
#endif
};

#ifdef PROXY

struct ProxyLogger {
      Logger& l;
      explicit ProxyLogger(Logger& l) : l(l) {}
      
      template <typename T>
      ProxyLogger& operator<<(const T& s) {
           l.out << s; 
           return *this;
      }
      ~ProxyLogger();
};

template<typename T>
ProxyLogger operator<<(Logger& l, const T& s) {
    l.out << s;
    return ProxyLogger(l);
}

ProxyLogger::~ProxyLogger() { l.out << std::endl; }

#endif // PROXY

int main() {
    Logger log;
    log << "test 1 " << 123;
    log << "test 2 " << 456;
    abort();
}
```